How to adjust a node width in a sankey plot in R?
I am running into a problem when creating a sankey plot because of the structure of my data.
Below is a sample dataframe. I am interested in the transformations of each feature across different stages and need the node sizes to represent a number of features per category at each stage. The problem is that at Stages 1 and 2 some of the features have two assigned categories.
I need sankey to show that:

at Stage 1: 2 features = A, 3 = B, and 2 = C
at Stage 2: 2 features = D, 1 = E, 2 = F, 2 = G,
at Stage 3: each feature is assigned only one value, so I want the nodes at this stage to be equal in the plot
at Stage 4: 4 features = f, 1 = g

df = data.frame(Features = c("Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3", "Feature4", "Feature5"),
                Stage1 = c("A", "A&B", "B", "B&C", "C"),
                Stage2 = c("D", "D&E", "F", "F&G", "G"),
                Stage3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                Stage4 = c("f", "f", "f", "g", "g"))

I split the values in the nodes with more than one category
library(tidyr)

df_sep <- df|>
  separate_rows(Stage1, sep = "&")|>
  separate_rows(Stage2, sep = "&")

Now, I tried using ggsankey, but when make the df_sep long, the splitted rows are dublicated, and since the node size is controlled by the frequency in "x" and "next_x" columns, the node sizes at the Stage 3 become unequal.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)

sankey_data <- df_sep |>
  ggsankey::make_long(Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4)

ggplot(sankey_data, aes(x = x, 
                        next_x = next_x, 
                        node = node, 
                        next_node = next_node,
                        fill = node,
                        label = node)) +
  geom_sankey()


I tried looking into networkD3, but the code below gives my a blank white sheet, not sure what's happening there...
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

links <- df_sep |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4), 
               names_to = "source", 
               values_to = "target") |> 
  group_by(source, target) |>
  summarise(value = length(unique((Features)))) 

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

Any suggestions on how can I controll the size of the nodes in ggsankey? Or how what is the problem with networkD3? Or better to use another package alltogether in this case? Or maybe some ideas on how to manipulate the data differently to fix this?

You can add value as an argument, with the value with this information. Check out this example

Thanks! I've ovelooked this. I am still not sure how to make this work with more then two columns though, as the value in the make_long function is defined per row, and the values in my case would be different for each pair of nodes (stages), so I would have 3 different values per each row. I was trying to look into the function and see if it can be adjusted, but my R skills are not sufficient for that :/

The sankey plot you've posted looks correct to me given the data you're using, so I'm not sure which lines you think are duplicated.
The networkD3 code does not work because you must refer to the nodes in your links data frame with the 0-based index of the nodes in your nodes data frame, which you can achieve like this...
df = data.frame(Features = c("Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3", "Feature4", "Feature5"),
                Stage1 = c("A", "A&B", "B", "B&C", "C"),
                Stage2 = c("D", "D&E", "F", "F&G", "G"),
                Stage3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                Stage4 = c("f", "f", "f", "g", "g"))

df_sep <-
  df |>
  tidyr::separate_rows(Stage1, sep = "&") |>
  tidyr::separate_rows(Stage2, sep = "&")

links <-
  df_sep |>
  dplyr::mutate(row = dplyr::row_number()) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = dplyr::starts_with("Stage"),
    names_to = "col",
    names_pattern = "Stage(.*)",
    names_transform = as.integer,
    values_to = "source"
  ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(target = dplyr::lead(source), .by = "row") |>
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(target)) |>
  dplyr::summarise(value = dplyr::n(), .by = c(source, target))

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))

# use the 0-based index of nodes in the nodes data frame as the ID
links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

networkD3::sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source_id",
  Target = "target_id",
  Value = "value",
  NodeID = "name",
  fontSize= 12,
  nodeWidth = 30
)
#> Links is a tbl_df. Converting to a plain data frame.



Thanks! This is super helpful for my understadnig of networkD3. What I wanted though is to find a way to regulate the size of the nodes by number of 'Features' assigned to each letter, e.g., at the stage with a, b, c, d, e all nodes should be of the same size bacause there is one 'Feature' per letter. That would require though, that the flows change thickness between the stages, and I figure that this is not how Sankey works, so that was perhaps the wrong choice of visualisation to start with :/

That size (technically, height) of each node is determined by the maximum sum of values of the links going in or out of the node. You could adjust the values of the links to fix the node size, e.g. set the value of the outgoing links from A and C to 0.33 each and the value of the outgoing links from B to 0.2 each, but as you have already surmised that is not how snaky plots are intended to work.
